# Bay Window Defense Combat Strength Bonus

Tags: untagged

When a Bay Window is added to a tower and has 1 or 2 marksmen on it, does it provide +1 value to defense strength when resolving strength at any one wall section connected to it ? Or does it provide +1 strength to resolutions for both wall sections connected to the tower it is on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the rules [here](http://portalgames.pl/files/rules/stronghold_rulebook_www.pdf) it says (emphasis mine):-

> Gain 1 Strength at **both** Wall sections adjacent to this Tower
>   during Melee combat if there is at least one Marksman present.